# Oracle 11g | Fastest way to select with an array of Ids

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle11g

I am currently working on a project which needs to extract hundred thousands of rows by their ids.
To do this we use a multithreading concept. The code is written in java.

I'll put some pseudo code in this explanation so that you can imagine the concept better. FYI: The concept works fine but the selection is way to slow for our requirements.

First, all the ids of the desired rows are selected and stored in a List. This list is used to provide the threads with the the ids of the rows that they need to select.

**This is the class that starts the threads which extract the rows:**

```
public class ExtractionService {
    private int maxAmountOfThreads = 10;
    private int maxAmountOfMessagesPerThread = 1000;
    private int rowsReserved = 0;
    private int messagesProcessed = 0;
    private int messagesToProcess = 0; // value set later
    private List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

    public void selectMessages(selectionAttributes) {
        final ExtractionService extractionService = this;

        ids = dao.selectIds(selectionAttributes)   // selectionAttributes holds the configuration to only select the ids of the rows that match the users filter
        messagesToProcess = ids.size(); // can be for example 150'000

        // If there are less rows returned than maxAmountOfThreads * maxAmountOfMessagesPerThread decrease the max amount of threads generated
        if((messagesToProcess / maxAmountOfThreads) <= maxAmountOfMessagesPerThread ) {                         
            maxAmountOfThreads = (int) (Math.ceil((float)messagesToProcess / (float)maxAmountOfMessagesPerThread ));                    
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < maxAmountOfThreads; i++) {                       //Create threads with start index (first messages to process for example starts at message 1001) and end index (last message to process in this thread for example 2001)
            int startRowIndex = messagesProcessed + rowsReserved;
            int lastRowIndex = ((startRowIndex + maxAmountOfMessagesPerThread < messagesToProcess) ? startRowIndex + maxAmountOfMessagesPerThread : messagesToProcess);

            threadArray.add(i, new Thread(new TransactionExtraction_Thread(startRowIndex, lastRowIndex, extractionService)));           
            threadArray.get(i).start();

            rowsReserved = rowsReserved + (lastRowIndex - startRowIndex);
        }

        boolean threadsAlive = true;
        while (threadsAlive) {
            threadsAlive = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.size(); i++) {
                if (threadArray.get(i).isAlive()) {
                    threadsAlive = true;
                    break;
                } else if(!threadArray.get(i).isAlive() && (messagesProcessed + rowsReserved) < messagesToProcess) {
                    int startRowIndex = messagesProcessed + rowsReserved;
                    int lastRowIndex = ((startRowIndex + maxAmountOfMessagesPerThread < messagesToProcess) ? startRowIndex + maxAmountOfMessagesPerThread : messagesToProcess);

                    threadArray.set(i, new Thread(new TransactionExtraction_Thread(startRowIndex, lastRowIndex, extractionService)));
                    threadArray.get(i).start();

                    rowsReserved = rowsReserved + (lastRowIndex - startRowIndex);

                    threadsAlive = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once a thread started, it will create a sublist of the ids-list with the start-
 and end-index that it has been given.

**This is the run() method of the threads**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = processor.getDao().extractRows(processor.getIds().subList(startRow, lastRow));

        while(rs.next()) {
            // DO STUFF WITH THE ROWS
            processor.setMessagesProcessed(processor.getMessagesProcessed() + 1);       // Increase the amount of processed messages by 1
            processor.setRowsReserved(processor.getRowsReserved() - 1); 
        }           
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Failed to execute extraction query!");
        log.error(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Failed to close ResultSet");
            log.error(e);
        }
    }

    log.debug("Thread ended");
}
```

The query is built by putting the list of ids which the thread holds into an sql "IN ()" form.

The simplified SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', ..., ....)
```

This "IN ()" is the performance-point I am talking about. It can hold up to the max amount of messages per thread which is defined in the service class. So in our example it is possible that it holds up to 1000 String-ids which it has to iterate through.

**Is this the most performant way to do this "bulk-selection"?**

Comment: Aren't you just doubling the amount of work that the DBMS is doing here? To get the list of ID's it has to visit all the rows that you will eventually want to retrieve so don't you end up visiting each row twice - once to get the id and then once to get the data associated with the id?

Comment: This is correct. But since the full select can return a big amount of data, depending on the filter I am not sure if a single select can handle it (millions of rows once we leave the testing environment). That's the reason why we even use the multithreaded solution. I just want to know if the "IN ()" -part is performant for this use. @DaveH

Answer (score 0):

The use of IN clause in SELECT will have performance impact and also you are limited to use upto 1000 values in IN clause.

Instead I'll would suggest in following way.

---

```
maxThreads=10
numberOfRecordsPerThread=5000

create threadArray as per required size. // ThreadPoolExecutor is recommended

select min(ID) as minValue, max(ID) as maxValue from TABLE;

String query="select column1, column2, ... from TABLE where ID > ? and ID =< ( ? )"

for(int i=0; i <= (maxValue-minValue/numberOfRecordsPerThread); i++ )
{
    query="select column1, column2, ... from TABLE where ID > minValue and ID =< ( minValue + numberOfRecordsPerThread)"
    exceute the query and store result in resultSet
    maxValue = maxValue + numberOfRecordsPerThread; // increment for next iteration
    start a thread with resultset if any-thread is available in threadArray
}

run()
{
    // Read the resultSet and do the stuff here.
```

### }

Comment: Well I don't think that this solution will work. Because the user can enter some configurations that affect which rows have to be selected a simple min / max(id) won't work. It can't just select all rows from 1 - 1000 because some of the rows won't match the users configuration.@Krishna